# Android - Match three separate conditions to enable/disable a button

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `username`, `password` and `checkbox` input for `Login` activity.
I need the `loginButton` to be enabled only if ALL three conditions are met (that is `username` is not blank, `password` is not blank and the `checkbox` is checked).
I can add `TextChangedListener` on `username` and `password`, and set `OnCheckedChangeListener` on the `checkbox`, but they all "listen" independently.

My code is below:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val imgURL =
            "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/leto-blue-ui-generic-1/64/ui_-16-512.png"

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(imgURL)
            .into(header)

        email.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                loginButton.isEnabled = s?.let { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: false
            }

        })

        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
            override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean) {
                if (checkbox!!.isChecked) {
                }
                else{
                }
            }
        })

        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            loginSuccessfulOperation()
        }


    }

    private fun loginSuccessfulOperation() {
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        loginButton.isEnabled = false

        Handler().postDelayed({
            loginButton.isEnabled = true
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.login_successful, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }, 2000)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. First, Declare three global variables as:

   ```
   private var isEmailEntered = false
   private var isPasswordEntered = false
   private var isCheckBoxChecked = false
   ```
2. Then, Create a function to check whether all three are checked:

   ```
   //You can use the line without this function as well
   fun isFormComplete(){
       loginButton.isEnabled = isEmailEntered && isPasswordEntered && isCheckBoxChecked
   }
   ```
3. In `afterTextChanged()` of both the `TextChangedListener()` of Email and Password, do:

   ```
   //For Email's TextChangedListener
   isEmailEntered = !s.isBlank() //s is the Editable argument of afterTextChanged() here
   isFormComplete()
   //For Password's TextChangedListner
   isPasswordEntered = !s.isBlank() //You can also use isNullOrBlank()
   isFormComplete()
   ```
4. In `onCheckedChanged` of `OnCheckedChangeListener()` of the `CheckBox`, do:

   ```
   isCheckBoxChecked = isChecked
   isFormComplete()
   ```

This will also hide the button again if user deliberately deletes any text or uncheck the checkbox. But, after all, this is just the one way of doing it which you can further customize yourself like to check if the entered email is valid beforehand with a threshold of textSize or any other logic like if it contains @ first to minimize function calls. You should also check password the same way first to minimize the function calls.

Function to check for a valid email :

```
private fun isEmailValid(email: CharSequence?): Boolean {
    val expression = "^[\\w.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$"
    val pattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    val matcher: Matcher = pattern.matcher(email!!)
    return matcher.matches()
}
```

Check it as `isEnteredEmailValid = isEmailValid(editable) //In your case, editable variable is named s`

Also, instead of using `isEmailEntered` and `isPasswordEntered`, you can use `email.text.toString().isBlank()` or `isNotBlank()`. As I said, it's just the one way of achieving it. Difference between `isEmpty()` and `isBlank()` is empty means nothing in the `EditText`, blank means nothing or only white spaces.

May this help.

Comment: Hi, Lalit. Thank you for your feedback. In 4 I think "isCheckBoxChecked = b" has to be "isCheckBoxChecked = true"?
On another note, with this code, if I uncheck the checkbox the LOGIN button does not become incative. It remains active.

Comment: @matua Change it to `isCheckBoxChecked = b` to `isCheckBoxChecked = isChecked` because the boolean argument of `onCheckedChanged()` is `isChecked` in your case, it's mostly `b` so I presumed it without looking at your code. I've updated this in the answer as well,.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. Thank you @Lalit Fauzdar for your tremendous support!